# Ubuntu 20.04 - White screen on skype when sending doc or pdf files?

Tags: skype, pdf

A strange issue appeared today while I was using Skype (snap version) and it looks persistent, since logging out and reboot didn't fix it.

When I send a document to another person, Skype turns white and is not responsive. I need to quit by the tray icon.

Here is an example of what's happening

[Example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMBJx.png)

Do you know how to solve this ? I can always use the web app through rambox, but it would be a little inconvenient.

Thanks in advance.